# How to match a User Record to Saved Search in NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, netsuite

I am trying to create an array of objects by loading a search and pushing the results to an array:

```
var searchArr = [];

    var dfaSearch = search.load({
        id: 'id_of_search'
    });

    var runSearch = dfaSearch.run().getRange({
        start: 0,
        end: 100            
    });
    for (x=0; x<runSearch.length;x++) {
        var engine = runSearch[x].getValue({
            name: 'id_of_department_column'
        })
        var approver = runSearch[x].getValue({
            name: 'id_of_approver_column'
        });
        var lowT = runSearch[x].getValue({
            name: 'id_of_lowerapproval_column'
        });
        var upT = runSearch[x].getValue({
            name: 'id_of_upperapproval_column'
        });

       var  searchCriteria = {
          engine : engine,
          approver: approver,
          lowT : lowT,
          upT : upT 
       };

       searchArr.push(searchCriteria);
    }
```

I have some more code that will load the Current User's record to grab internal ids, etc. However, when trying to test with a static ID for department I keep receiving :

```
TypeError: Cannot find function find in object.
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
function findApprover(approverInfo) {
     return approverInfo.engine === '26';
}
var approverInfo = searchArr.find(findApprover);
log.debug({
   title : 'Current User Approver ID',
   details : approverInfo
});

}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) method was introduced in ES2015 and is not supported by NetSuite. You could try using a 3rd party library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#find) which includes polyfills for ES2015 methods like `find`:

```
function findApprover(approverInfo) {
     return approverInfo.engine === '26';
}

var approverInfo = _.find(searchArr, findApprover);

log.debug({
   title : 'Current User Approver ID',
   details : approverInfo
});
```

Or search for the approver in a different way, for instance, using a for loop:

```
function findApprover(array, key, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][key] === value) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var approverInfo = findApprover(searchArr, 'engine', '26');

log.debug({
   title : 'Current User Approver ID',
   details : approverInfo
});
```

Comment: Thank you Andre! I can't figure out how to get the underscore library to actually work, but the second solution (for loop) worked perfectly.